# committed by the disease

Tags: sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

> They got **committed by the disease** during the gathering.

1. Is **committed by the disease** right word usage? What I want to say is they got infected by the disease during the gathering.
2. **They got (verb) by (noun)** is this sentence structure correct and why?

Comment: "What I want to say is 'they got infected by the disease during the gathering.' "   That is what you should say.  Why would you want to use the verb "commit" what do you think it means?

Comment: @JamesK I am not sure of whether it is correct with using 'commit'; therefore the asking - is it wrong?

Comment: Yes. Perhaps if you can quote the dictionary definition I could understand your question better

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to say:

> They **contracted** the disease during the gathering.

Contract (verb) = to become affected with ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contract))

You can say in more informal way:

> They **got** the disease during the gathering.

Comment: Exactly that is what I am trying to get to, contracted is the right word, thanks Jan